# Как обработать ошибку в Api android

Tags: android, kotlin, api

Вот мой код с работающим Api, в целом он работает нормально. Это Погодный Api, в котором я подставляю города, и он выдает погоду в определенном городе. Но у меня возникает проблема, если я подставляю неправильный город, которого не существует, соответственно, из Api сервера я получаю какую-то ошибку, которую я хотел бы обработать и сделать тост, в котором я говорю вам ввести правильное название города.

> Api

```
interface ApixuWeatherApiService {

    @GET("current.json")
    fun getCurrentWeather(
        @Query("q") location: String,
        @Query("lang") languageCode: String = "en"
    ): Deferred<CurrentWeatherResponse>

    @GET("forecast.json")
    fun getFutureWeather(
        @Query("q") location: String,
        @Query("days")days: Int,
        @Query("lang")languageCode: String = "en")
    :Deferred<FutureWeatherResponse>

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(
            connectivityInterceptor: ConnectivityInterceptor
        ): ApixuWeatherApiService {
            val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
                val url = chain.request()
                    .url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addQueryParameter("key", API_KEY)
                    .build()
                val request = chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build()
                return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
            }
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptor)
                .build()
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ApixuWeatherApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

> Log FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.ggenius.wtw, PID: 28498 retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory$BodyCallAdapter$adapt$2.onResponse(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.kt:104) at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:123) at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153) at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
> LocationProviderImpl

```
const val USE_DEVICE_LOCATION = "USE_DEVICE_LOCATION"
const val CUSTOM_LOCATION = "CUSTOM_LOCATION"


class LocationProviderImpl(
    private val fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient,
    context: Context) : PreferenceProvider(context), LocationProvider {

    private val appContext = context.applicationContext

    override suspend fun hasLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {
        val deviceLocationChanged = try {
            hasDeviceLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
        } catch (e: LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
            false
        }

        return deviceLocationChanged || hasCustomLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)
    }

    override suspend fun getPreferredLocationString(): String {
        if(isUsingDeviceLocation()) {
            try {
                val deviceLocation = getLastDeviceLocation()
                    ?: return "${getCustomLocationName()}"
                return "${deviceLocation.latitude},${deviceLocation.longitude}"
            } catch (e: LocationPermissionNotGrantedException) {
                return "${getCustomLocationName()}"
            }
        }
        else {
            return "${getCustomLocationName()}"
        }
    }

    private suspend fun hasDeviceLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {

        if (!isUsingDeviceLocation())
            return false

        val deviceLocation = getLastDeviceLocation()
            ?: return false

        // Comparing doubles cannot be done with "=="
        val comparisonThreshold = 0.03
        return Math.abs(deviceLocation.latitude - lastWeatherLocation.lat) > comparisonThreshold &&
                Math.abs(deviceLocation.longitude - lastWeatherLocation.lon) > comparisonThreshold
    }

    private fun hasCustomLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation: WeatherLocation): Boolean {

        if (!isUsingDeviceLocation()) {
            val customLocationName = getCustomLocationName()
            return customLocationName != lastWeatherLocation.name
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun getCustomLocationName(): String? {
        return preferences.getString(CUSTOM_LOCATION, null)
    }
    private fun isUsingDeviceLocation(): Boolean {
        return preferences.getBoolean(USE_DEVICE_LOCATION, true)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private suspend fun getLastDeviceLocation(): Location? {
        return (if (hasLocationPermission())
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.asDeferred()
        else {
            throw LocationPermissionNotGrantedException()
        }).await()
    }

    private fun hasLocationPermission(): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}
```

> Здесь использую ApiService

```
class WeatherNetworkDataSourceImpl(
    private val apixuWeatherApiService: ApixuWeatherApiService
) : WeatherNetworkDataSource {

    private val _downloadedCurrentWeather = MutableLiveData<CurrentWeatherResponse>()
    override val downloadedCurrentWeather: LiveData<CurrentWeatherResponse>
        get() = _downloadedCurrentWeather

    override suspend fun fetchCurrentWeather(location: String, languageCode: String) {
    try {
        val fetchedCurrentWeather = apixuWeatherApiService
            .getCurrentWeather(location,languageCode)
            .await()
        _downloadedCurrentWeather.postValue(fetchedCurrentWeather)
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("Connectivity", "UnCorrentCITY", e)
        val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        pref.edit().putString("CUSTOM_LOCATION", "London").apply()

    }
}
    private val _downloadedFutureWeather = MutableLiveData<FutureWeatherResponse>()
    override val downloadedFutureWeather: LiveData<FutureWeatherResponse>
        get() = _downloadedFutureWeather

    override suspend fun fetchFutureWeather(
        location: String,
        languageCode: String
    ) {
        try {
            val fetchedFutureWeather = apixuWeatherApiService
                .getFutureWeather(location, FORECAST_DAYS_COUNT, languageCode)
                .await()
            _downloadedFutureWeather.postValue(fetchedFutureWeather)
        }
        catch (e: NoConnectivityException) {
            Log.e("Connectivity", "There is no internet connection.", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А где код, который это все хозяйство вызывает? Там надо смотреть и ловить ошибки. Первый пример, что попался: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62288530/5479247

Comment: Я добавил изменение, в функции getCustomLocationName я меняю название города

Comment: В последнем я пытаюсь обработать ошибку но не работает все ровно

Comment: И что вы там пытаетесь обрабатывать? `NoConnectivityException`? А что вам прилетает? `retrofit2.HttpException`? Ловите его там где оно выстреливает и разбирайтесь почему.